# What is a formula for calculating overlapping downtime periods in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, downtime

I have periods of downtime per calendar month and I wish to calculate the total:

| Outage Start | Outage End | Outage (mins) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/10/2021 15:00 | 05/10/2021 18:00 | 180 |
| 06/10/2021 16:00 | 06/10/2021 18:00 | 120 |
| 06/10/2021 17:00 | 06/10/2021 19:00 | 120 |
| 07/10/2021 16:00 | 07/10/2021 18:00 | 120 |
| 25/10/2021 08:00 | 25/10/2021 09:32 | 92 |

Summing the last column gives 632, but this is inaccurate as the period of downtime specified by row 3 overlaps that specified by row 2. I need a formula which takes this into account and gives the correct answer of 572.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

- your rows are in ascending order
- and the Start and End columns are of Date/time data type

You can check if the current start time is in between previous start & end and then calculate the remaining time.

```
=IF(AND(A2>A1,A2<B1),B2-B1,B2-A2)*1440
```

[image: Outage difference working formula screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you need a copyable formula, then use

```
=(MIN(B2,A3)-A2)*24*60
```

if you need a total amount in one number, use this array formula:

```
=SUM(((IF((B2:B6<A3:A7),B2:B6,IF(A3:A7<>"",A3:A7,B2:B6)))-A2:A6))*24*60
```

[image]